# Can't access shell variable in crontab configuration

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, environment-variables

I have problem in accessing a shell variable while running cron job. Actually i created a job which prints two shell variable values into a `env.output` file.

I am writing cron job using command `$ crontab -e` (without sudo user).

My crontab configuration file looks like this:-

```
# varibales
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
     /usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAILTO=abc@xyz.com
HOME=/home/ubuntu
JOBS_PATH=${HOME}/cronjobs

# Jobs
* * * * * echo "$HOME and $JOBS_PATH" >> ${HOME}/env.output 2>&1
```

So, now when i see the contents of file `env.output` , i get this output

```
/home/ubuntu and ${HOME}/cronjobs
```

which is not expected i assumed.

I want my output should looks like this:-

```
/home/ubuntu and /home/ubuntu/cronjobs
```

Suggest me some way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have problem in accessing a shell variable

`HOME` as defined at the top of a crontab is not a shell variable, is an environment variable.

You can't reference environment variables at the top of a crontab, as no shell processes them and thus they're not expanded (and interpreted literally).

You'll have to set `JOBS_PATH` manually:

```
# ...
JOBS_PATH=/home/ubuntu/cronjobs
# ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of the cron daemon. See this from the [manpage of crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/crontab.5.html):

> The value string is **not** parsed for environmental substitutions or
>   replacement of variables, thus lines like:
>
> ```
>      PATH = $HOME/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> will not work as you might expect.

You can do a workaround, since bash treats the tilde (`~`) as substitution of `$HOME`. Therefore use:

```
JOBS_PATH=~/cronjobs
```

Comment: Upvoted this since apparently it works, but I'm still a bit puzzled at *why* it works. AFAIU environment variables set at the top of a crontab are processed by `cron`, not by the shell. Could you expand on this a bit? Mainly I don't understand why a variable wouldn't be expanded but a tilde would, seems pretty much an arbitrary behavior (i.e. it looks like that is handled that way by `cron` on purpose).

Comment: sorry @kos i was in hurry , so i wrongly upvoted this answer. Your solution works really. Now i write full path to environment variable.